# Keeping user session alive with Azure Function

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, timer-trigger

Since I cannot trigger a Timer-based function with a queue or providing it with a param (session id to keep it alive, refreshing it every 30 minutes), is it possible to create a basic HTTP/Queue Function (and NOT Timer function) and add a c# code inside with a custom timer? Will the function once triggered run forever?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices > avoid long running functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No as @Will mentioned in his comment, you cannot use **Azure Function** to run forever (continuously). As the design of Azure  Functions is intended to work for less load with-in specific time limit.

The [time limit of Consumption Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan)  says

> The default timeout for functions on a Consumption plan is 5 minutes.
>   The value can be increased for the Function App up to a maximum of 10
>   minutes by changing the property function timeout in the host.json
>   project file.

So as a best practice you should avoid long running jobs in Azure Function.

For your use case, you can use [Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-overview). Azure Web Apps are the one which is designed for long running jobs.

1. You can create a basic HTTP/Queue Function
2. Which in turn cal your
3. Azure Web Apps Azure web apps then run forever as you wish.